# why covariant type parameters are used only for the return types of the members?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Why covariant type paramaters like `IEnumerable<out T>` type `T` used only for the return type (read-only) or inverse contravariant type parameter like `Action<in T>` type `T` used only as parameter type (write-only)?
in other word i think there exist a relation between pure covariant concept and c# covariant type paramaters used only for the return types of the members.

Comment: Co-variance means that a *return*-type can be an instance of the type or one of its derived ones on calls to `MoveNext`. Is your question why microsoft chosed to implement it this way? Or what is your *actual* goal you want to achieve?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thank you for attention.I think exists relation between pure covariant concept and c# covariant type paramaters used only for the return types of the members.my actual goal is understand this relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do covariant type parameters like `IEnumerable<out T>` have type `T` used only for the return type?

First off: `T` does not *have* to be used only for the return type. For example:

```
interface I1<out T>{ T M1(); }
interface I2<out T>{ void M2(Action<I1<T>> a); }
```

In `I1<T>`, `T` is used only in return type positions.  But in `I2`, `T` is used in an input `a`, and an `I1<T>` is the input of the `Action`, so in a sense it is being used in *two* input positions here.

But let's consider just a simpler case. Why can we make `I1` covariant in `T` but not contravariant in `T`?

The reason is because covariance is safe and contravariance is not.  We can see that covariance is safe:

```
class Animal {}
class Mammal : Animal {}
class Tiger : Mammal {}
class Giraffe : Mammal {}
class C : I1<Mammal> {
    public Mammal M1() { return new Tiger(); }
}
I1<Mammal> i1m = new C(); // Legal
I1<Animal> i1a = i1m; // Legal
Animal a = i1a.M1(); // Returns a tiger; assigned to animal, good!
```

No matter what `C.M1` returns, it is always a `Mammal` and therefore always an `Animal`.

But this cannot be legal:

```
I1<Giraffe> i1g = i1m; // Not legal
Giraffe g = i1g.M1(); // Returns a tiger; assigned to giraffe, bad!
```

The first line has to be illegal so that the second line never executes.

Now you should have enough information to figure out why contravariance works the way it does.  Remember, you can always come back to a simple example and ask yourself "if this was legal, what mistakes could I make later?"  The type system is protecting you from making those mistakes!

Exercise: Do this same analysis of `I2<T>`.  Do you see why it is legal to use `T` in *two* input positions even though it is `out`.  (Hint: `Action` is *contravariant*, so it reverses the direction of assignment compatibility. What happens if you reverse directions *twice*?)

Comment: Thank you kindly.Why `interface I2<out T>{ void M2(Action<I1<T>> a); void M3(T t); }` is not legal?

Comment: @MatinMoezi: Again: ask yourself *if it were legal, what trouble could I get into?*  Suppose you have `class C : I2<Mammal> { public void M3(Mammal m) { m.GrowHair(); } }`  That seems perfectly legal.  Now suppose you have `I2<Animal> a = new C();`  That's the step that needs to be illegal, but suppose it was legal.  Then `a.M3(new Turtle());` would also be legal, and we just grew hair on a turtle.  The conclusion is that the variance annotation is wrong, and so the interface will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

So i see where is your problem. Answer should be this way. Let me again use example from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index):

```
static object GetObject() { return null; }  
static void SetObject(object obj) { }  

static string GetString() { return ""; }  
static void SetString(string str) { }  

static void Test()  
{  
    // Covariance. A delegate specifies a return type as object,  
    // but you can assign a method that returns a string.  
    Func<object> del = GetString;  

    // Contravariance. A delegate specifies a parameter type as string,  
    // but you can assign a method that takes an object.  
    Action<string> del2 = SetObject;
    //However you can't use del2 this way, after this assingment:
    //del2(new object);
}
```

This is hard to understand and for me it is quiet high level of abstraction.

### Covariance

Let's take a closer look to `Func<object> del = GetString;`
You are allowed to do such thing because string derives from object, so as long as you will get a method with return type derives from object you don't have problem with it. Imagine you declare the same del so all you know you will get object so you declare a variable:

```
object returnedType = del2();
```

You don't have to care about whether del2 return int or string because they derives from object it will be similar with:

```
 object returnedType = "string"; //Here we know what is on the left side
 //If we assign to del2 method with return type string.
```

### Contravariance

Now let's take a look to `Action<string> del2 = SetObject;`
Now you assume that you will get a string to method so if somebody, someday will use your delegate with method like `SetObject(object obj)` so it will be the same as earlier:

```
object obj= "string"; //Here we know what is on the right
```

### Assuming

it's all about pure polymorphism. In covariance, we except one general type but it changes nothing for us if we get more specific type.
In contravariance we know what we will passing, but it doesn't matter if we will assign string to string or string to object. (but we can't assign object to string).